# Lost data using async await HttpResponseMessage and EventSource

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using server-sent events to send messages to and from a jquery EventSource. I'm using some JQuery code and two c# controller classes for this as per below. The issue I have is the EventSource stream receives nothing from the server eventhough all paths are correct and I am not getting any errors in the web browser or in the server classes. Can you suggest ways to identify and fix the problem? I'm including code for WebApiConfig.cs and relevant code for Global.asax.cs. It seems the issue is the data gets lost before it can be read through the event source. How can data be made to persist? Thanks.

Here's the code I have:

1. Client:

```
evtTaskSSESource = new EventSource('/' + strAccountIdx1 + '/Admin/Tasks/GetHttpTaskSSEs/');

evtTaskSSESource.onmessage = function (event) {

    if (event != undefined && event != null) {

        console.log(event.data.toString());
    }
};
```

2. Two server-side controller classes:

2a. One server-side controller class called TasksController:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TBDotNet.Web.Controllers
{
    private static HttpClient httpClient = null;

    public class TasksController : Controller
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetHttpTaskSSEs()
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient();

            httpClient.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
            
            string strAPIPath = MainUtilities.GetLocalServerURL() + "/MyID/api/sse_api/GetTaskSSEs";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(strAPIPath);

            // Check if the response is successful
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Get the content of the response as a string
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Return the content as a ContentResult object
                return Content(content, "text/event-stream");
            }
            else
            {
                // Return an error message as a ContentResult object
                return Content("Something went wrong", "text/event-stream");    //text/plain
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2b. One server-side controller class called sse_apiController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;

namespace TBDotNet.API.Controllers
{
    public class sse_apiController : ApiController
    {
        #region Global objects

        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public sse_apiController()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        #endregion

        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }

        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetTaskSSEs()
        {
            string retVal = string.Empty;
            HttpRequestMessage request = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            await Task.Delay(1);

            request = Request;

            response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Random content");
            
            // Set the content of the response object to a PushStreamContent object with the content type "text/event-stream"
            response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, context) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Use a while loop to check the value of MainUtilities.GetTaskSSEs("TaskStage")
                    while (MainUtilities.GetTaskSSEs("TaskStage") != "RatingCycleEnded")
                    {
                        retVal = MainUtilities.GetTaskSSEs("TaskStage");
                        if (!CommonUtilities.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
                        {
                            MainUtilities.SetTaskSSEs("TaskStage", string.Empty);
                            // Use response.StatusCode and response.IsSuccessStatusCode instead of Response.StatusCode and Response.IsClientConnected
                            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                UnicodeEncoding uniencoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
                                byte[] result = uniencoding.GetBytes(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", "TaskStage|@@|" + retVal));

                                await stream.WriteAsync(result, 0, result.Length);
                                await stream.FlushAsync();
                                result = null;
                                uniencoding = null;
                            }
                        }
                        // Remove the break statement to allow multiple events to be sent to the client
                        //break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MainUtilities.HandleErrorEvent(false, false, DateTime.Now, string.Empty, ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        stream.Flush();
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }, "text/event-stream");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

3. In WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Routing;

namespace TBDotNet.Web
{
    public class WebApiConfig   //https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-routing
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Add a route prefix for all controllers within the "api/app" namespace
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

4. In Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```